# Socket programming - Converting Windows code into linux code

Tags: c, sockets

i'm quite new to socket programming and my task is to change a windows code into linux. There i got a problem and i hope you can help me. I got this code segment, where the four parameters of the IP4-address get transfered from a function to my socket code (in windows with the header winsock.h).

```
struct sockaddr_in server;

server.sin_addr.S_un.S_un_b.s_b1 = (unsigned char)a1;
server.sin_addr.S_un.S_un_b.s_b2 = (unsigned char)a2;
server.sin_addr.S_un.S_un_b.s_b3 = (unsigned char)a3;
server.sin_addr.S_un.S_un_b.s_b4 = (unsigned char)a4;
```

My question is, if there is a similar type of way to transfer these parameters to the linux socket code.

Comment: the server is defined like this:    `struct sockaddr_in server;`

Comment: Please edit your question to add this information

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can convert it manually:

```
inaddr_t make_inaddr(
            unsigned char a1,
            unsigned char a2,
            unsigned char a3,
            unsigned char a4)
{
    inaddr_t result;

    result = htonl(((uint32_t)a1 << 24) 
                    | ((uint32_t)a2 << 16)
                    | ((uint32_t)a3 << 8)
                    | a4);
    return result;
}
```

Comment: @Kilian Then it is about time to accept ✓ this answer in order to encourage other people to give good answers.